# Conditional static?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming, type-traits

Consider the following class :

```
template<bool Condition> class MyClass
{
    protected:
        /* SOMETHING */ _var;
};
```

With a `std::conditional<Condition, const int, int>::type _var;` I can choose if `_var` is a const or a non-const through the template parameter.

How to do the equivalent for static/non static ?

(I ask for an equivalent though whatever metaprogramming technique you want)

Comment: How would you *use* such a design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to do it using a helper struct, since static is not part of the type but a storage specifier. For example:

```
template <class T, bool Static>
struct StaticSelector
{
  T value;
};

template <class T>
struct StaticSelector<T, true>
{
  static T value;
};

template<bool Condition> class MyClass
{
    protected:
        StaticSelector<float, Condition> _var;
};
```

That being said, easy switching between static and non-static is probably a bad idea..

Comment: I see certain problems with the static object definition, if T != int

Comment: static requires definition: `template <class T> T StaticSelector<T, true>::value;`. But what if `T` does not have default c-tor?

Comment: You might get closer to the OP's wishlist if you made `MyClass` *inherit* from `StaticSelector`, instead of containing it as a member.  But yeah, I have to agree with Kerrek's comment on the OP: Why on earth would you *want* something like this?

Comment: @Quuxplusone You can implement guaranteed storage elision this way, to force compilation without a variable in memory but just access to the static methods. You can call static methods just like strorage-based member methods.